# "list out of range" thrown when trying to remove rows in list of list where list[i][0] and list[i][1] == 0

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am trying to remove rows in an array that have `0` values for the first two columns. My code is:

```
  for i in range (5680):
        if games[i][0] == 0 and games[i][1] == 0:                   
            games.pop(i)
  print(games)
```

Putting a print statement of `games[i][0]` and `games[i][1]` in under the second line prints out a whole bunch of lines of `0`'s so I know that these rows do exist.I am getting a `list out of range` error, even though games is a `5680` by `5` matrix.
No matter what I try changing the error is still thrown. Whats going on?

Comment: Full traceback and an example representation of `games` would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to change an object that you are iterating through is almost always a bad idea. In your case after first `pop()` you have list that is already smaller than 5680. So when you get to 5679 you are already out of range.

Try this:

```
games = [g for g in games if g[0] != 0 or g[1] != 0]
```

or

```
games = list(filter(lambda g: g[0] != 0 or g[1] !=0, games))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're removing rows from `games` (as you do with `games.pop(i)`), it will no longer have 5680 rows, so as long as you remove at least 1 row, and you eventually try to access `games[5679]`, which will give you 'list out of range' since you no longer have that many rows.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as `games.pop(i)` is called, the dimension of the `games` matrix goes from 5680x5 to 5679x5, and decreases with each successive call. At the same time, `for i in range(5680)` keeps iterating through `[0, ..., 5680]`, meaning that some later `i` will definitely be out of range.

There are a variety of ways to keep this from happening. One simple way is to check the indices of `games` in reverse order. That way, if an index `game_index` is popped, the next index in the iteration, `game_index - 1`, will still exist in the matrix.

```
# iterate in reverse order
for i in range(5680, 0, -1):
    game_index = i-1
    if games[game_index][0] == 0 and games[game_index][1] == 0:
        games.pop(game_index)

print(games)
```

This procedure is good in general if you expect to pop only a few items. If you expect to pop the majority of items, it may be more performant to create a new list.

```
games = [game for game in games if game[0] != 0 and game[1] != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're altering the list while you iterate through it.
This fails.  Once you pop the first item, you no longer have 5680 elements in the list, so you cannot access those last elements.

Instead, use a **filter** operation to generate a new list.

```
new_games = filter(lambda row: row[0] != 0 or row[1] != 0, games)
```

[Handy examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/05/python-filter-and-list)